# How to store the user uuid and role after authentication in spring security JWT

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

Hello I want to store the userUUID and role extracted from the JWT for all database queries.
Right now Im passing the useruuid and role as request param for each request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should store these in the JWT payload itself.
Parse JWT and verify signature if present, on each request and then use them accordingly.

These details should never come from user input or a place where user can modify them.